# Minimizing direction of a continuous function defined everywhere except at one point and directional limits.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-continuity

Let $F: \mathbb R^n \setminus \{ x^*\} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function defined everywhere except at a point $x^* \neq 0$. Assume that all directional limits of $F$ at $x^*$ exists, i.e,

$$ L(h) := \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} F(x^* + \epsilon h) \quad \text{exists in 
 $\mathbb R$ for all} \quad h \neq 0. $$

Assume further that the finite minimum of $F$, denoted by $\lambda$, is **only** attained "at" $x^*$, i.e, $F(x) > \lambda, \forall x \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ x^*\}$ and there exists a sequence $x_n$ converging to $x^*$ such that
$$ \lambda := \inf F = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} F(x_n).$$
Then is there an $h^*$ such that $\lambda = L(h^*)$?

An (incorrect) example of such function, with infimum also attained at (1,2), is
$$ F(x,y) = \frac{3(x-1)^2 +(y-1)^2}{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2}, \quad (x^*,y^*) = (1,1), \quad \lambda = 1 = L((0,1)), \quad h^* = (0,1). $$

What I know is if $F$ is **uniformly** continuous then the answer is **yes**. However I think that when we remove uniformity then there should be a counter example. Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** Added "only attained at $x^*$" in the assumption on the infimum.

Comment: For a counterexample, try modifying the standard example of "directional limits exist but limit doesn't": $x_1x_2^2/(x_1^2 + x_2^4)$. Of course you will need to translate $x_1, x_2$ e.g. substituting $(x_1 - 1)$ instead of $x_1$ to make $x^\ast \neq 0$.

Comment: @0XLR Thank you for your suggestion. In fact, I was not so precise in the question. It should read: the infimum is "only" attained at $x^*$. Do you know how to modify your example such that the infimum is only achieved by a minimizing sequence and not at any other points? When I wrote this, I was imagining F is going down near $x^*$ and that each directional limit can be different.

Comment: @0XLR And even my example is not in that spirit as well, I apologize for this...

Comment: Yes, that's a very annoying extra condition that you should have been clear about from the beginning. The more niche a condition is, the more it is likely to derail a solution and waste time if you don't add it beforehand. Anyway, here's an intuition that you can flesh out yourself. The above function achieves its minimum $-1/2$ across the whole curve $y^2 = -x$. Try to make an artificial example that "adds a little to that curve" away from $(0, 0)$ to force the minimum to be at $(0, 0)$. Or try to "slightly fold" the graph of the above function upwards along $x_1 = 0$.